# OpenSSL 1.0.0l compilation error

Tags: linux, openssl, cross-compiling

I'm cross compiling OpenSSL 1.0.0l in linux but i'm getting error like

```
eng_cryptodev.c:57:30: error: crypto/cryptodev.h: No such file or directory

sh-linux-gnu-gcc -I.. -I../.. -I../asn1 -I../evp -I../../include  -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -
DZLIB_SHARED -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DL_ENDIAN 
-DHAVE_CRYPTODEV -DUSE_CRYPTODEV_DIGESTS -DHASH_MAX_LEN=64 -DTERMIO -O3 -fomit-frame-  
pointer -Wall   -c -o eng_dyn.o eng_dyn.c
sh-linux-gnu-gcc -I.. -I../.. -I../asn1 -I../evp -I../../include  -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC - 
DZLIB_SHARED -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DL_ENDIAN  
-DHAVE_CRYPTODEV -DUSE_CRYPTODEV_DIGESTS -DHASH_MAX_LEN=64 -DTERMIO -O3 -fomit-frame
-pointer -Wall   -c -o eng_cryptodev.o eng_cryptodev.c
eng_cryptodev.c:57:30: error: crypto/cryptodev.h: No such file or directory
eng_cryptodev.c:73: error: field \u2018d_sess\u2019 has incomplete type
eng_cryptodev.c:105: warning: \u2018struct crparam\u2019 declared inside parameter list
eng_cryptodev.c:105: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is    
probably not what you want
eng_cryptodev.c:106: warning: \u2018struct crparam\u2019 declared inside parameter list
eng_cryptodev.c:107: warning: \u2018struct crypt_kop\u2019 declared inside parameter list
```

Please let me know if anyone have any idea about this error

Comment: It's from -DHAVE_CRYPTODEV -DUSE_CRYPTODEV_DIGESTS. If you have hardware support for crypto, you would set these and build the interface for your hardware, and need cryptodev.h. Normally you don't need this.

Answer (score 0):

```
sh-linux-gnu-gcc -I.. -I../.. -I../asn1 -I../evp -I../../include  -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC - 
DZLIB_SHARED -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DL_ENDIAN  
-DHAVE_CRYPTODEV -DUSE_CRYPTODEV_DIGESTS -DHASH_MAX_LEN=64 -DTERMIO -O3 -fomit-frame
-pointer -Wall   -c -o eng_cryptodev.o eng_cryptodev.c
eng_cryptodev.c:57:30: error: crypto/cryptodev.h: No such file or directory
eng_cryptodev.c:73: error: field \u2018d_sess\u2019 has incomplete type
```

I'm pretty sure that's used by the BSD's for `/dev/crypto`. But its not present in OpenSSL's 1.0.0l:

```
$ wget http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.0l.tar.gz
Resolving www.openssl.org (www.openssl.org)... 185.9.166.106
...
$ tar xzf openssl-1.0.0l.tar.gz 
$ cd openssl-1.0.0l/
$ find . -name cryptodev.h
$
```

You might try undefining `HAVE_CRYPTODEV` with `-UHAVE_CRYPTODEV`.